# error in reading csv file to plot graph

Tags: csv, svg, d3.js

i am just not able to read a csv file .I want to  display a graph for it.
I am getting error: 
TypeError: n is undefined

please help me out!!

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function(dataset){
var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
var xScale=d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(dataset.length)).rangeRoundBands([0,w],0.05); 
var  yScale=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset.value)]).range([0,h]);

svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset).enter().append("rect").attr({x:function(d,i)    {return xScale(i);}, y:function(d){
return h-yScale(d);}, width:xScale.rangeBand(),height:function(d){return    yScale(d);},fill:function(d){return  "rgb(0,0,"+(d.value*10)+")";}});

     d3.select("svg").selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text").text(function(d)       {return d.value;}).attr("x",function(d,i){
return xScale(i)+xScale.rangeBand()/2;}).attr("y",function(d){return             h-yScale(d)+14;}).attr("font-family","sans-serif").attr("font-size","10px").attr
("fill","white").attr("text-anchor","middle");

d3.select("p").on("click",function(){
var numValues=dataset.length;
dataset=[]; 
for(var i=0;i<numValues;i++)
{var newNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
dataset.push(newNumber,newNumber);
}
yScale.domain([0,d3.max(dataset)]);
svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset).transition().delay(function(d,i){return     i/dataset.length*1000;})
.duration(500).attr("y",function(d){return h-yScale(d); }).attr("height",function(d)    {return yScale(d);}).attr("fill",function(d){
return "rgb(0,0,"+(d.value*10)+")";});
svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).transition().delay(function(d,i){return        i/dataset.length*1000;}).duration(500).text(function(d){return d.value;})
.attr("x",function(d,i){return   xScale(i)+xScale.rangeBand()/2;}).attr("y",function(d)    {return h-yScale(d)+14;})
.attr("font-family","sans-serif").attr("font-      size","10px").attr("fill","white").attr("text-anchor","middle")
                     ;});


});
```

here is my csv file
    names,value
    john,78
    brad,105
    amber,103
    james,2
    dean,74
    pat,45
    matt,6
    andrew,18
    ashley,15

Comment: It's pretty hard to let what's going on but here are some things to check.  Are you trying to load the file locally? Most browsers won't allow javascript to call a local file.  To avoid this use a local server.  More obvious is have you checked that your file is where you expect to be?  Have you tried to console log the dataset?

Comment: yes the file was successfully read by the browser,i checked it by console.log

Comment: There are lot of errors in this code, for example max inside yScale should be calculated like this d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return +d.value;}) instead of d3.max(dataset.value) and in y:function(d){
return h-yScale(d);} there should be  y:function(d){
return h-yScale(d.value);} and so on...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by cuckovic there are quite a few errors in your code, not to mention that you seem to be using different styles to achieve similar things which is confusing.  Anyway there are 3 fundamental things that are casuing you trouble, the first is your dataset.  The value column of the csv is being read as a string.  You need to convert it to a number by:

```
dataset.forEach(function (d,i) {
    d.value = +d.value;
});
```

The next issue you have is the yScale where you have set the range to `.range([0,h]);`. This is the wrong way round for an svg viewport in which the y direction starts from top and increases towards the bottom.  So you need to swap the 0 and h around in the range.

The next thing to address is the difference between `d` and `d.value`.  When you bind data through the `data()` operator you are generally binding an array.  In this case it is an array of objects.  So after you have bound the data, `d` refers to each element of that array which in this case is an object containing a *name* and a *value*.  This can be seen if you `console.log` your dataset.  When `d` is passed to `yScale` it doesn't know what to do with it as it is not a number, what you really want to do is to pass `d.value` to `yScale`.  So replace your `d`'s with `d.value`.

Finally, the last part of your code starting at `d3.select("p")` does not seem to add anything.

I'd recommend reading Scott Murray's tutorials, particularly this [one](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart) if you haven't already.